# Circle Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anybody know how to create a circle layout for a screen in landscape mode in Android? Like actually as in this image:

[image: Sample Image]
The following is my XML file for a screen in portrait mode:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_inbox" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_service_inbox" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_service_compose" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_private_inbox" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pa_compose" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_alert_compose" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_alert_inbox" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_private_compose" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pa_inbox" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_header_footer_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_Home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_Back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_footer_info_bg"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="MY HOME : "
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/xx_Small"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_MyHome"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/xx_Small" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="NEIGHBOURHOOD : "
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/xx_Small"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_Neighbourhood"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/xx_Small" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please check my code and help me.

Comment: instead of `RelativeLayout` use your own custom `ViewGroup` implementation and override its `onLayout` method, or find some already existing implementations on the web

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: if you dont know how to start, better follow the answer below

Comment: But i want it in landscap . In portrait its looks ok.

Comment: so if Android-CircleMenu / WearCircleMenu are not good for you then make a custom `ViewGroup`, use google for more info: `custom ViewGroup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check below links For testing case . I hope it will helps you .

1. [Android-CircleMenu](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu)
2. https://android-arsenal.com/tag/138
3. [WearCircleMenu](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/WearCircleMenu)